# Papyrus: Hide/remove base_Class property from stereotypes

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

Is there a way to hide or remove the various `base_Class` properties that appear together with the properties defined for a stereotype? I am close to deploy a profile and I am pretty sure this will generate some confusion among the users.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you really don't want to remove the 'base_*' properties as these indicate the meta class that your stereotypes extend. When a user goes to apply your profile, the meta class extension allows the UML editor e.g. Papyrus to display appropriate stereotypes for the target UML element. So if a user wants to apply your profile to a UML Class element, without the 'base_Class' property, nothing will show up. These extensions are linked to other elements within your profile so just removing them will cause your profile to "break" elsewhere. Other typical meta class extensions might be Property i.e. a 'base_Property' will show up. There are many others.

Oh ok cool. So when your users apply the profile to a model this takes place, as you know, primarily under the Profile->Applied stereotypes area of the Properties editor. The meta class extension properties are definitely not visible there, at least on my Papyrus version. Using Modeling Luna 4.4.0

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but I am aware of this. These properties (and others) should be filtered by Papyrus and not shown to the user, but for some reason all the `base_Class` properties of each stereotype are appearing.